# Is it possible to compile/link to occi with gcc on HPUX?

Tags: oracle, gcc, hp-ux

We have Oracle 11 running on HP-UX 11.31 and gcc 4.4.3. It seems that there is no way to link to occi, because it was built with aCC. Is there any workaround for this?

I had the silly idea that I could somehow build a library that basically proxied the connection - build the library with aCC in some way that could be linked to by gcc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way around that.

Different C compilers have interchangeable code using a standard ABI.  You can mix and match their object code more or less with impunity.

However, different C++ compilers have a variety of different conventions that mean that their object code is not compatible.  These relate to class layout (especially in multiple inheritance hierarchies and the dreaded 'diamond-of-death'), but also in name mangling conventions and exception handling.  The name mangling schemes are deliberately made different so that you cannot accidentally link objects from one compiler with another.

Generally, if libraries are built using a C++ compiler, you have to link your code using the same - or at least a compatible - C++ compiler.  And that almost invariably means a compiler from the same family.  For example, you might be able to use G++ 4.5.0 even if the code was built with G++ 4.4.2.  However, you won't be able to mix aCC with G++.